# MySQL sub-query optimization

Tags: mysql

I've got a query that is running awfully slow:

```
SELECT * 
FROM games
WHERE games.platform =13
AND games.id NOT 
IN (SELECT game_id
FROM collections
WHERE collections.user_id =1)
```

I attempted to rewrite it as a left join but it's returned 0 results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM games 
LEFT JOIN collections ON collections.game_id = games.id 
WHERE collections.game_id IS NULL AND collections.user_id = 1 AND games.platform = 13
ORDER BY games.name ASC
```

Could someone point out my error here?

Comment: try that using #FULL OUTER JOIN because it will point to you everything, and what does not match will return as null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT games.* 
FROM   games 
       LEFT JOIN collections 
         ON collections.user_id = 1 
            AND collections.game_id = games.id 
WHERE  games.platform = 13 
       AND collections.game_id IS NULL 
ORDER  BY games.name ASC
```

you need indexes on

- (games.id,platform,name)
- (collections.user_id,collections.game_id)

Comment: I think the best indexes are `games(id)` and `collections(user_id, game_id)` select * makes the rest moot. Consider also changing `select *` to `select games.*`

Comment: You guys are rockstars! Thanks.